# Perl Can't locate XML/Simple.pm

Tags: perl, ubuntu

I am working on Perl, and when I run my script I got the error said :

```
Can't locate XML/Simple.pm in @INC
```

Comment: are you behind a proxy?

Comment: @stevieb I think no.

Comment: what happens if you `ping cpan.mirror.rafal.ca`? Does the DNS name resolve to an IP address?

Comment: @stevieb ping: unknown host cpan.mirror.rafal.ca

Comment: it seems your DNS is borked then. Can you browse websites from within a browser on that system (or even via `wget`)? The one specified should take you to the front page of a CPAN mirror. If not, can you browse to its IP (`207.210.46.249`)? It should display simply `It works!`

Comment: @stevieb I saw  "It works!"

Comment: by IP or by name did it work?

Comment: @stevieb yes, it show it works.

Comment: at the `cpan` shell, try this: `o conf urllist unshift http://www.cpan.org`, then attempt to install the module (`install ...` from within the cpan shell you're still in). If that fails, `o conf urllist unshift http://207.210.46.249`, and try install again. These changes will be deleted if you exit the cpan shell, so don't, until you're done testing.

Comment: @stevieb thank you, I am following your answer to do it and see.

Comment: @stevieb  connection failed. I got  http://207.210.46.249/authors/01mailrc.txt.gz
LWP failed with code[500] message[Can't connect to 207.210.46.249:80 (Connection timed out)]

Trying with
    /usr/bin/wget -O "/root/.cpan/sources/authors/01mailrc.txt.gz.tmp32529"
to get
    http://207.210.46.249/authors/01mailrc.txt.gz
--2016-09-13 14:53:23--  http://207.210.46.249/authors/01mailrc.txt.gz
Connecting to 207.210.46.249:80... failed: Connection timed out.
Retrying.

Comment: are you positive you're not behind a proxy server? Check your browser settings...

Comment: @stevieb I saw the config and the 'http_proxy' => q[]

Comment: in your web browser (eg: Firefox, Chrome etc), do you have a proxy set in the network configuration?

Comment: @stevieb lets me double check. thank you.

Comment: let me know. if one is in use, I'll write an answer showing how to fix it

Comment: @stevieb thank you very much. I will.

Comment: @stevieb I think its the proxy problem, thank you very much, but I need to install this behind the proxy. what can I do right now? We are not allowed to download anything behind the proxy. I use WinSCP to download the file and put into Putty, but I think it not the only one I need to install. Is there any way to solve this problem?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're already getting help in comments for getting CPAN installs working correctly, but most common Perl modules can also be installed from the Ubuntu repositories.  In this case, you should also be able to `sudo apt-get install libxml-simple-perl` to install it from Ubuntu.  If that's not the correct package name (I use Debian rather than Ubuntu, so it's possible Ubuntu may have renamed it), you can use `apt-cache search XML::Simple` to get a list of matching packages, then check their details with `apt-cache show [package name]` to determine which is the one you want.

Note, however, that the [XML::Simple](https://metacpan.org/pod/XML::Simple) documentation advises *"You really don't want to use this module in new code."*  If you are writing new code, you should probably look into another XML module.  I personally use [XML::Twig](https://metacpan.org/pod/XML::Twig), which happens to offer a `simplify` method which produces output very much like that from XML::Simple, although you're probably better off getting used to the more robust node-based interface.

Comment: thank you, I use 'sudo apt-get install libxml-simple-perl' to see what happened, and I got:

Comment: Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
The following extra packages will be installed:
  libencode-locale-perl libfile-listing-perl libfont-afm-perl
  libhtml-form-perl libhtml-format-perl libhtml-parser-perl
  libhtml-tagset-perl libhtml-tree-perl libhttp-cookies-perl
  libhttp-daemon-perl libhttp-date-perl libhttp-message-perl
  libhttp-negotiate-perl libio-html-perl liblwp-mediatypes-perl
  liblwp-protocol-https-perl libnet-http-perl libwww-perl
.............//many lines here
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y

Comment: sudo apt-get install libxml-simple-perl     is working